# ls vs. dir in cygwin/uwin in Windows 7

Tags: cygwin, ksh, dos, ls, dir

I was trying to process a directory of over 10000 files using ksh in Cygwin in Windows 7 and have found that it can take well over a minute before processing can begin because I start by doing an

```
ls -r | while read....
```

I can get all the files in a few seconds by doing a

```
set *
for file; do
```

but that isn't in the date order. The only way I have found around it right now is by running a MSDOS shell and using "dir" like this:

```
cmd /c "dir /b /a-d /o-d" | while read...
```

Is there any simple way of doing this without having to run a dos shell and why does "ls" take so long anyway?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to eliminate some possibilities, could you confirm that you still get the same problem when running the `ls` by executing the binary, like so... `/usr/bin/ls -r`?

Comment: Ah ha! Yes, doing a /usr/bin/ls -r had it run fast. I did a `type ls` and it came back with it as an alias for `ls -hF --color=auto`. After a little experimenting it turns out that the `-F` option was causing the lag. Thank you very very much.